# Select records where Time.now is between two datetime fields

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, time

I have `starts_at` and `ends_at` columns in an `Activity` table.

What I want to do is select all records where `Time.now` is between the datetimes in those two columns.

Comment: Can you add sample rows of your table in the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
Activity.where("? BETWEEN starts_at AND ends_at", Time.zone.now)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do simply:

```
now = Time.now
Activity.where('starts_at < ? AND ends_at > ?', now, now)
```

You can also use inclusive inequality operands instead (`<=` and `>=`)

Answer (score 0):

Try squeal gem,  you will like it, then you can use this:

```
Activity.where{starts_at < Time.now & ends_at > Time.now}
```

Or second option can be.

Actualy Unlike some ORMs, active record doesn't augment the symbol class with methods to allow expressions other than equality to be expressed in this way. You just have to do

Activity.where('starts_at <= ? AND ends_at >= ?', Time.now, Time.now)